# admob ads are not showing up but a simple button is

Tags: android, admob

i have this **manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.fcporto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>


<application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".Principal"  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application></manifest>
```

and my main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" android:id="@+id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TabWidget android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/tabs"></TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#013364"
                android:id="@+id/tab1">
                <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView2"
                    android:background="#efefef" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#013364"
                android:id="@+id/tab2">
                <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:background="#efefef" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tab3">

                <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/webview"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#013364"
                android:id="@+id/tab4">
                <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/listView3"
                    android:background="#efefef" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>
            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" >


     <com.google.ads.AdView    
       android:id="@+id/ad" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="my_unit_id" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/></LinearLayout></TabHost>
```

If i replace **this**

```
<com.google.ads.AdView    
       android:id="@+id/ad" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="my_unit_id" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
```

by a simple **button**, this works. What i am missing with the admob?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You didn't replace "my_unit_id" with your actual admob publisher id.
2. There is no ad to show.  Keep in mind that the fill rate on ad requests is not 100%.  Check your Logcat output.  If you see a message saying something like "Ad Request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of inventory", then it means no ad is available.

Answer (score 1):

When you're testing this all out to make sure it works appropriately, you can turn on "testMode" for the ad.  You'll have better luck in development with that on.