# How to hide title bar when back to onresume?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

When I run app, leave the app, and then return (minimize or phone goes to sleep) my app's layout seems to have a title bar above even if I have try to use

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

How can I fix this?

addition:

I know the cause of this problem is about ads if I put ads at the top of screen everything is alright like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a14e854c3d48d14"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <TabHost 
     android:layout_below="@+id/adView1"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="2">
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipperContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_tab_menu"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
   </TabHost>
   </LinearLayout>`
```

but the problem is occur when I try to move ads to the bottom of screen so what should I do?

Comment: Try to use relative layout and set add view to bottom.

Comment: 10-20 14:10:12.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16633): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379066/admob-ads-are-not-showing-up-but-a-simple-button-is  check it

Comment: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html